# I'm stuck with rounding decimals and have been for years

Tags: education

I'm in year 10 and have a B grade - yet still manage to mess it up when I face a question regarding decimals. For example:
Round 8.647 to one decimal place.
Would this be 8.7 or 8.6 as I have never understood if the third number affects the second number first.

Also recurring decimals, say for example:
Round 8.56565656 to two decimal places
Would this be 8.67 and the first and second are rounded, or 8.57, or 8.56?
Finally,
Would 8.045 = 8.05? or 8.15?

Comment: Maybe just as a trick, you might multiply 8.647 by ten and then round to the nearest whole number. Is it any easier to see that 86.47 rounds to 86?

Comment: The thing is that you need to know if you are closer to $8.6$ or to $8.7$. And if you are in the middle, you go up (by convention).

Comment: It can help to visualize the numbers on the number line.  Kind of like [this](http://brightcove04.o.brightcove.com/1257553535001/1257553535001_1809486321001_vs-503c53fad92eb0e416092041-767904719001.jpg?pubId=1257553535001) for example.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc There are many different conventions for what to do when rounding from an exact midpoint value - I would say that the most 'common', particularly in computer sciences, is to round so as to make the last digit even - so 8.645 would round to 8.64, while 8.655 would round to 8.66.

Comment: OK, I did not know this strange convention, but thanks for explaining it. I would say that in maths, this is the other one that we use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want a number correct to $i$ decimal places. Just look at the $i+1$ th digit. If its a $5$ or greater, round up. If its a $4$ or lower, round down.

- Round down = forget everything after the $i$th digit
- Round up = forget everything after the $i$th digit, and increment the $i$th digit by $1$.

For example, if you want $8.647$ correct to $1$ decimal place, you need to be looking at the digit immediately after the $6$. In this case its $4$. So you round down. Final answer: $8.6$

Comment: The only argument with this is what to do with exactly $5$.  There are various standards.  You are always rounding up, which is one standard.

Comment: @RossMillikan true; im just repeating the convention we were taught in high school.

Comment: Brilliant answer, however how would I round the recurring decimal?

Comment: @HarryKitchener, the only trick with recurring decimals is that if there's an infinite tail of $9$'s (as in 4.1399999...) you first have to eliminate the tail. Replace the $9$'s with $0$'s and increment the number immediately to the left of the tail. e.g. in this case we increment $3$. So we get $4.14$ (which is equal to the number we started with, just written more simply). Now you can apply the usual rules. Hence if you want  $8.56565656...$ to two decimal places, just apply the rules given in my answer (since there is no recurring tail of 9's).

Comment: So basically, look at it like $(8.56)(5)(65656...).$ Notice that we've got a $5$ in those lonely brackets. So we round up. Final answer; $8.57$.

Comment: @HarryKitchener please comment if that's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

To round to either $8.6$ or $8.7$, compare them with the middle value of both which is $8.65$. The question is do you have :$$8.647 < 8.65\qquad \text{ or } \qquad 8.647 \ge 8.65$$

In the first case you round *down* to $8.6$, in the second case you round *up* to $8.7$.

Same goes with $8.565656$, take the middle value of $8.56$ and $8.57$, which do you have :$$8.565656 < 8.565\qquad \text{ or } \qquad 8.565656 \ge 8.565$$

If your problem is comparing decimals, I suggest you have a look at this [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/decimals/comparing-decimals/v/comparing-decimals) video which explains it well.